Applying inverses functions to an inequality
The generalization for an increasing function has the step
$$P(u(X))<y)=P(X<v(y))$$
which is justified on that page graphically.
Can I justify it algebraically by saying that since $Y=u(X)$ is a continuous increasing function, we can apply the inverse function $v(y)$ to both sides of the inequality
$$u(X))<y$$
and the inequality remains valid.

All you need is increasing. If decreasing, change the direction of the inequality
